# How Can I Enter Username And Password Outputs To A MySQL Server Without Using POST or GET

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have 2 html text input fields and a button, a basic sign in page. when the button is pressed, using Jquery it transforms the page to somewhat of a menu. i want the values to be sent to the server and checked then log in. I struggled because i couldn't find a way to get the javascript variables to php variables then sent to the server and couldnt find any way to do this without using POST or GET. using a form to work with post or get messed up the animations that i made with query.

any help is appreciated, i just want to know how to turn the javascript variables to php ones then to send them off

Comment: When you submit the form, why not have a php check function in a separate php file; grab the values in jquery and perform a get or post to that file which can return back a true/false if the credentials are matching; your user doesn’t have to leave the page you can check the credentials quietly with a simple Ajax call and return a result back to indicate what should happen next

Comment: If the menu transform is for the user after a successful login, then have the jquery menu animation run in the success handler of a standard jquery $.POST request that sends your form data to the server to be checked against your database, rather than fire the animation off the submit button.This lets you deal with errors in authentication the way you want as well. Never use a GET request with sensitive data, as the data is appended to the URL for anyone to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer... you can't. POST and GET are methods, and describe to the server what format the data has been sent in, so it can then populate either the PHP $_POST or $_GET arrays with the data sent from the form.

However, this can be accomplished without reloading the page using a jquery ajax POST request that sends the data to the server to validate against your database, and you can then fire the menu animation on the success handler of the ajax request, which is returned if the login was successful.

I might add, it is important that you also be encrypting and hashing the passwords in your SQL login database for best security practices.